# Windows 7 64 Bit - ODBC32 - Legacy App Problem

Tags: sql, windows-7, odbc, legacy

Good day StackOverFlowlers,

I´m a little stuck (really stuck) with an issue with a legacy application on my organization.

I have a Windows 7 Enterprise 64 Bit machine, Access 2000 Installed and the Legacy App (Is built with something like VB but older) The App uses System ODBC in order to connect to a SQL 2000 DataBase on a Remote Server.

I created the ODCB using C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe app in order to create a System DSN. I did not use the Windows 7 because it is not visible to the Legacy App.

I tested the ODBC connection with Access and worked ok, I can access the remote database.

Then I run the legacy App as Administrator and the App can see the ODBC, but I´m getting errors on credential validation and I´m getting this error:

```
    DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Multi-Protocol]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) 

    DIAG [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Multi-Protocol]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53) 

    DIAG [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed (0)
```

I use Trusted Connection on the ODBC in order to validate the user by Domain Controller.

I think that the credentials are not being sent by the Legacy App to the ODBC, or something like that. I don´t have the source code of the Legacy App in order to debug the connection.

Also, I turned off the Firewall.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you run it as administrator is it your same account elevated or is it a second account all together?

Try running Access 2000 under that same method and see if it can still access the database. You can also check the SQL server logs to see who the app is trying to authenticate as. This should help you identity where to start looking.

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for the tip, I use the same account elevated. When I do this on Access, I can see the database with no problem. Let me check the SQL Log and check what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joshua, I´m using sql profiler on the SQL database but find no transaction related to the user validation. In which database this happens? I should be able to find the error I get in the profiler right?

Comment: Not necessarily. The SQL server logs will be on the actual server itself. By default it should log login failures to the Application Event Log on the server. You may need to contact the DBA to get that information.